# What are usual objections to allowing SNAPSHOT level in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, isolation-level

What are the usual objections raised by DBAs when developers request the DBA to allow SNAPSHOT isolation level in a SQL Server 2008 database? Read Committed SNAPSHOT is not being requested but simply isolation level of SNAPSH

Comment: All the snapshot-based isolation levels make use of `TempDB` which is often a badly configured, badly maintained part of SQL Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't say there usually are objections. As a DBA, I actively encourage development teams to let me use the Read_Committed_Snapshot isolation level. In fact, I prefer it. As it says in the comments, I will see an increase in the use of tempdb because of it, but the reduction in blocking is well worth the cost.

I'm not as crazy about the use of SNAPSHOT because, usually, I can't sell developers on the idea that they need to change their code, which they do. Also, because it's completely dependent on the developers to correctly code it's use, I see more errors, places where it won't work or where it creates problems. That's why I'd rather just enable the isolation level at the database.

I'm sure this is fixed now, but several years ago a project I was working on had problems using SNAPSHOT with nHibernate. I don't remember any of the details, just that they hit issues, but it was quite a while back.

Comment: Today, our DBA, just emailed me that usually they don't allow SNAPSHOT isolation level. I am sure he will have a meeting with me. **What can I tell him to convince him to allow SNAPSHOT isolation level?**

Comment: Which isolation level? Just SNAPSHOT through connections, as I said above, I'm not crazy about that one either because it's too dependent on all the code being done correctly. If it's read_committed_snapshot, find out why he's objecting. Usually it's a lack of knowledge of how it works, or, a concern about the added load on tempdb. If it's the latter, do a quick Bingle search on tuning tempdb. There are some standard best practices published, especially on the Microsoft MSDN web site, that will help.

Comment: Grant, Appreciate your response. The reason our DBA comes up with is that there are about 100 databases being used in production and it will be difficult to manage tempdb with SNAPSHOT isolation level Or READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT turned on.  I hope I can convince him. Let's see.

Comment: Easier to manage tempdb a little differently than deal with lots of resource contention.